# trigger onresize in cross browser compatible manner

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, onresize

I would like to trigger the onresize event from my C# code behind. I think this can be done with

```
Page.clientScript.RegisterScriptBlock(this.getType(), "id", "javascript code");
```

I have tried element.onresize() but it doesnt seem to work in firefox. What is the correct way to trigger an onresize event similar to the following jQuery?

```
$("body").trigger("resize");
```

Using jQuery itself isn't an option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do the trick, [DOM Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-DocumentEvent-createEvent), no idea whether this works in IE6, quirks mode still has no information on this stuff:

```
if (document.createEvent) {
    var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    e.initEvent('resize', true, false);
    document.body.dispatchEvent(e);

} else if (document.createEventObject) {
    document.body.fireEvent('onresize');
}
```

Tested in FF, Chrome and Opera.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EhLgB/2/ Does not work in IE8 this does seem to be an IE8 thing

Comment: Yes, works with IE 10, FF 24.0, and Chrome 30.0. Doesn't appear to work with Opera 12.16. +1 anyways and I'll check where I can find a solution for Opera. I didn't check Safari.

Answer (score -1):

use this `$(window).resize();`
(tested in FF, chrome, IE8)

// old answer, fails in FF
`document.body.onresize()`

Comment: Using jQuery isn't an option for me. This needs to work generically all over the websit without relying on jQuery being included.