# Is there a way to trigger a window.onresize event in a cross browser way?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [trigger onresize in cross browser compatible manner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856098/trigger-onresize-in-cross-browser-compatible-manner)

I library I use has some code I need called attached to the window.onresize event. **Are there ways to fake this event programatically?**

- I can't call the attached event directly (one of my libraries is responsible for it and this is precisely the work I wish I could avoid)
- I am *not* using Jquery
- Since I could't find how to do this through Google, I suspect what I want might not be possible. In this case, I would still be happy so see this confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onresize = function(e){
 alert("called"); 
}      
window.onresize();
```

If the browser is using the event object that is passed in, than you can just manulaly recreate that object yourself with the values that it needs.

```
window.onresize( { "whatever" : 1234, "someOtherValue" : "foo" } );
```

Comment: I can't do that. Their event was added via addEventListener so window.onresize is actually null.

Comment: No. It is attached to the window.

Comment: Show the exact code in your question. thanks

Comment: I don't think you got the point of the question :/

Comment: I got the point of the question, I asked to see the code that you are using so I can make a test page. ;)